# How do I write a script that will save an Excel file to another file at specific intervals?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a back-up copy of an Excel document.
How do I make it so that the macro runs automatically every time the document is saved?

Here is the code:

```
Sub BUandSave()  
  'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)  
  'Saves the current file to a backup folder and the default folder  
  'Note that any backup is overwritten  
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="G:\1 Processing\Christine\" & _  
 ActiveWorkbook.Name  
 ActiveWorkbook.save  
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
End Sub
```

I got this code from online and have zero skills with VBA, please help!

EDIT: Alright, thank you for your answers and insight. now I have one other question. How do I make it so that the back-up copy saves under a different name. I want to make it something like DO NOT DELETE or DO NOT EDIT, something like that so that the person editing the file doesn't accendentally try to edit the wrong one. How do I add that into the code?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the code you posted:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)  
'Saves the current file to a backup folder and the default folder  
'Note that any backup is overwritten  

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="G:\1 Processing\Christine\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name  
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
End Sub
```

Place the above code in your `ThisWorkbook` module (Alt + F11 will get you into the VBA Editor).
`Workbook_BeforeSave` is a workbook Event.  Code within it is executed whenever the event is triggered, in this case, before the workbook is saved.  Events in Excel are pretty darn cool and a powerfull tool for code slingers :-)
The code you posted in your question is now no longer necessary.

Comment: That's true... but if you're going to put it in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` just because it's more explicit. There's also no need for `ActiveWorkbook.Save` as the workbook will save as soon as the sub finishes unless the `Cancel` boolean is updated to false.